# Excel 2016 - Horizontal axis values for box and whisker chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have columns of values, each column contains only data collected in a specific year. But when I create BnW chart I get the years as labels for individual boxes rather than values on the axis.

Apart from that the graphs look as they should. But horizontal axis still shows just one generic value (1) instead of years and I can't select custom axis values as I would normally in Select data window.

Is there any way to have years on the horizontal axis instead of having them in the legend?